# Probleme post from node.js to mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm pretty new to nodeJS and i'm trying to send data from a register form to mongodb but I apparently made a mistake using the post method, since i can't visualize it on postman

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const registerData = require('./models/registerData');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res;
  render('index', { title: 'Accueil', description: 'Ceci est la page index' });
});

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  var rData = new registerData();
  rData.firstName = req.body.firstName;
  rData.lastName = req.body.lastName;
  rData.date = req.body.date;
  rData.email = req.body.email;
  rData.password = req.body.password;
  rData.save((err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.render('index', {
        title: 'Accueil',
        description: "Une erreur s'est produite",
      });
    }
    res.render('index', {
      title: 'Accueil',
      description: 'registerData a été sauvegardé',
    });
  });
  res.redirect('/');
});

module.exports = router;
```

here is the file where i declare my schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const registerDataSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  date: String,
  email: String,
  password: String,
});

const registerData = mongoose.model('registerData', registerDataSchema);

module.exports = registerData;
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you should **never** store passwords as clear text in your database. Store only hash-values.

Comment: ... and date values should **never** be stored as string either. Store proper `Date` objects.

Comment: Instead of a static error message like  "Une erreur s'est produite", you should return a proper error message, e.g. `"Une erreur s'est produite: " + err.message`

Comment: sure,  that is just a test to grasp how it works

Comment: Assuming the web server is started and the database connection is made, you will need to specify the parser for the request's payload. For example, `router.use(express.json())`.

Comment: It should be helpful to debug if you can share what is the HTTP response and logging info

Comment: No error occured, i just can't visualize anyhting on postman or get any data on mongodb.

Comment: Here is the link of the repo https://github.com/LuigiVampa21/ADVANCED-TLP if ever ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {

    const data = {
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        date: req.body.date,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    };
    rData = new registerData(data);
    rData.save((err) => {
        if (err) {
            res.render('index', {
                title: 'Accueil',
                description: "Une erreur s'est produite",
            });
        }
        res.render('index', {
            title: 'Accueil',
            description: 'registerData a été sauvegardé',
        });
    });
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for help but it isn't working either

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.